# EmberJS: How can i add specific Controllers after my application is already initialized to my Router?

Tags: ember.js

Actually we try to build a modular Webapplication with the EmberJs framework. 
At startup we want to load the Application with all core functions.... If the User interacts with the Application we want to reload several ember-widgets to the application, with own views and controllers. My question is, how can i inject the reloaded controllers and views to the application?

I try following:

```
App.getPath('router.applicationController.controllers').reopen({
    aController   : this.AController.create()
});
```

but this seems not to be work, as the controller not injected as i asspect.

Answer (score 2):

The good news: Your goal (to load core fx at startup and reload views/controllers as user interacts with app) is common to most ember applications.
The bad news: It doesn't work quite the way you are expecting, you may need to do some refactoring.

When router is initialized, it will create singleton instances of every controller class defined in the namespace. Controller instances are meant to be long-lived and should be lightweight to instantiate. For sure they should not be loading data in an init() or anything like that.

As user navigates to various routes in your app, use connectOutlets() to set appropriate data on controllers and bind them to views. Ember will automagically create/destroy instances of your view classes as needed. So basically anything you were looking to do when reloading controllers should happen here instead. For more detail on how this works, I'd recommend having a look at the section "Injecting Controller Singletons" in the router.js source: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/router.js#L295

If you follow the above approach, your app will meet the stated design goal without any need to inject controller instances into the router.

Make sense?

Comment: As i understand you right, it is not possible to add new controllers to the router at runtime. The Router have to know all controllers and views before i call initialize() method ?